# GSON - Json to Java parsing - How to keep the trailing zero

Tags: java, json, web-services, web, gson

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson; 
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;  

public class StudentMain { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"XYZ\", \"percentage\":95.90}"; 

      GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
      builder.setPrettyPrinting(); 

      Gson gson = builder.create(); 
      Student student = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Student.class); 
      System.out.println(student.getPercentage());  
   } 
} 

    package com.json;

    class Student { 
           private String name; 
           private double percentage; 
           public Student(){} 

           public String getName() { 
              return name; 
           }

           public void setName(String name) { 
              this.name = name; 
           } 

           public double getPercentage() { 
              return percentage; 
           }

           public void setPercentage(double percentage) { 
              this.percentage = percentage; 
           }

           public String toString() { 
              return "Student [ name: "+name+", age: "+ percentage+ " ]"; 
           }  
        }
```

It is displying 95.9 but I wanted to display 95.90. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: Change it to the format you would like to see in your toString method.

Comment: store percentage as a String instead of a double

Comment: Thanks @Jens. I am good now.

Comment: @MT756  Why it should stored as a string when thenformat is only needed for print out?

Comment: @Jens I don't see a problem printing out a String. As long as you are not doing any math operation on percentage, a String would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `toString` body with following code snippet:

```java
public String toString() { 
    return String.format("Student [ name: %s, age: %.02f]", name, percentage)
}
```

So you don't need to change `double` to `String`